# Identifying best pattern for exposing JS utility functions

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I'm trying to build a JS file for our project which will expose some generic utility functions. I've used the following two patterns before but not convinced with them entirely.

**Pattern 1**

```js
var objUtils = {
 foo: function(){
  //code
 },
 bar: function(){
  //code
  //foo can't be called
 }
}
```

The problem with the above pattern is that I can't invoke cross-invoke the functions.

**Pattern 2**

```js
var objUtils = (function(){
 var foo = function(){
 },
 bar = function(){
 }
 
 return{
  foo : foo,
  bar : bar
 }
})();
```

The problem with the above pattern is that every time I add a new function I've to make sure that I add it to the return block to make it exposed, which I feel is kind of a redundant work.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `foo` can be called inside of `bar` like `this.foo()` if you call it like `objUtils.bar()`

Comment: Named exports from ES6 modules are the one and only true way these days.

Comment: That was silly I din't try this.foo(). Way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript Module Pattern.
You create an object with the functions you want to expose and add your functions directly to this object. For example:

```
var objUtils = (function () {
    var moduleObj = {};

    moduleObj.foo = function () {
        // ...
    };

    moduleObj.bar = function () {
        // ...
    };

    return moduleObj;
}());
```